# how to read file in local PC from server with python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, server, path

I wish to read file from server with python. It is difficult to copy file to server because the file is too big. So how can I read local file from server? My local PC is Mac.

Comment: Is your server your PC?

Comment: Unless your local computer _is_ a server (NFS, FTP, Samba), another computer cannot access its local files. Also, unless you plan to read the file partially, there is no difference, performance-wise, between uploading it or reading from the server locally.

Comment: no, it's a remote server

Comment: You may be confusing the words 'server as a remote computer' and 'server as a computer that runs server software' (the latter one can be either local or remote).

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is with with

```
with open('yourserverfile.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print line
```

Comment: This code cannot be executed by a _remote_ server to read a _local_ file at the _local_ computer.